# Creating a scrollable button list menu in Unity from C# scripting

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, scroll

Hi guys I'm totally new to Unity3D. I'm trying to create a scrollable button list where users can scroll through a list of buttons inside a panel. So I have a OnGUI function and inside of it I created some buttons that are of the same width and height. Their Y-axis position is separated by about 55 units each. This is all done in Unity's C# script. I attached the script to a panel and that panel is also attached with a vertical scrollbar. I added the Mask component in the panel where I unchecked the Show Mask Graphic. But when I click play, the buttons do not show up at all. Is it possible to create a scrollbar inside the script and attach to the button list? Thanks

Comment: I advise you to add some code of what you've tried so people have something to work with before people start raining downvotes since you're basically asking "can I do X?" and the answer is with 99.9% certainty "Yes".

Comment: I am confused as to why this post has 3 upvotes without showing your code. I have a feeling that you are mixing/using [IMGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) with the new Unity UI system because you mentioned `OnGUI` and [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Mask.html) Component. This will **not** work. It's hard to tell exactly what you are doing without your code.

Comment: void OnGUI(){GUI.Button(new Rect(470, 175, 245,45), "Sample Button")}. So inside this function I keep on adding more buttons by incrementing PosY with about 40 units. On the Unity Scene, I have Mask Graphic unchecked

Answer (score 2):

Ok I would highly advise you use the new Unity UI system instead of using Immediate Mode GUI (OnGui functions). You can still control things programatically with ease but it is much easier with a canvas to work with.

You mention using panels and masks but they don't mix with the OnGui setup, that is the legacy UI system and should only be used for Unity editor plug ins.

That said there are great learning resources which cover exactly what you need in these three tutorials on the Unity site:

- [Scroll Rect Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect?playlist=17111)
- [Scroll Bar Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-scrollbar?playlist=17111)
- [UI Mask Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-mask?playlist=17111)

And if you have not got any experience using the newer system the main tutorial page is [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
(taken from the Unity Script Reference for [GUI.BeginScrollView](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.BeginScrollView.html))

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;
    void OnGUI() {
        scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(10, 300, 100, 100), scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 220, 200));
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 20), "Top-left");
        GUI.Button(new Rect(120, 0, 100, 20), "Top-right");
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 180, 100, 20), "Bottom-left");
        GUI.Button(new Rect(120, 180, 100, 20), "Bottom-right");
        GUI.EndScrollView();
   }
}
```

Comment: That answers may have been valid 3 years ago. OnGUI should only be used for Editor UI.

Comment: I don't think so. IMGUI has its own advantages, and for some people it's easier to understand and work with. The new GUI has its own quirks and issues and the out-of-the-box complexity there can be sometimes overwhelming.

Comment: @lilotop Funny. [IMGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) is mainly intended as a tool for programmers in Editor. Before the new UI came out, people used NGUI not IMGUI. Only hobbyist used IMGUI. People that published their games used NGUI or another UI plugin.

Comment: Another case of using the legacy UI is for assets on AssetStore. It allows the developer to display a UI with minimum effort from the consumer. But surely not for in-game UI.

Answer (score 1):

If its in game, I don't recommend OnGUI, rather use the Unity UI components. There is good video on how to create scrolalble lists here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUun2xW6FJ4

You can add buttons to the vertical or horizontal group easily from editor or from code. You just instantiate button prefabs and place them inside the horizontal group parent.

```
GameObject horLayoutGroup;
GameObject buttonPrefab;
var myButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, new Vector3(default), Quaternion.identity);
myButton.transform.SetParent(horLayoutGroup.transform)
```

this will automatically scale the entire layout group and place everything neatly next to each other, without having to play with pixel offset.

If you want to add a function to a button, you use the following code:

```
 myButton = GetComponent<Button>();
 myButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
 myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => SomeClassInstance.PublicFunction);
 myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => SomeOtherClassInstance.AnotherPublicFunction);
```